# samba upgrade on ubuntu

Tags: server, samba

good day , my name is saleem ali from trinidad and tobago . i would like some assistance - i have a server running samba along with squid but i would like to create a new server to run samba alone the other system is old and i want to upgrade it . the new server has ubuntu 14 lts and i would like to now what is the easiest way to migrate from the old server to the new server.
also i have a backup script running that backup the  complete etc file on an external if that would be of any help >>> thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Announce downtime to your users
2. stop samba on old server
3. copy data to new server
4. copy samba config to new server
5. start samba on new server and look at the logfiles

If everything is OK, announce the move to your users, if not, open an new question with the specific error message(s).